# Calculating sigmoid function value and computing its gradient at same point

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, logarithms, gradient-descent

my function for $a = a_i, 1 \le i \le 6$ is:

$\sigma(a) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-a}}$
$f(a) = \sigma\bigg[\log\bigg(5(\frac{a_3}{a_4}max(a_1,a_2)-(a_5+a_6))\bigg)+\frac{1}{2}\bigg]$

I am trying to evaluate $f(a)$ at $a = (5,-1,6,12,7,-5)$. Below are the steps I am taking:
$f(a) = \sigma\bigg[\log\bigg(5(\frac{6}{12}max(5,-1)-(7-5))\bigg)+1/2\bigg]$
$f(a) = \sigma(\log(5/2)+\frac{1}{2})$
$f(a) = \sigma(0.89794000867)$
$\hspace{10mm}= 0.710732054$

I am getting an answer of ~0.850 whereas the expected answer is 0.805. Can someone explain me with the steps and clarification of where I am going wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've suggested edits to your question; in addition to the changes I made, please clean up what you've written to explain it a little better.  For example, $max{a,b}.c$ is not clear.

Comment: Yes, and please include some more intermediate steps.

Comment: I've made further changes to your question to improve readability.  Please make sure they reflect your original intent.

Comment: Your last sentence says you expect a result of 0.805 but you're getting 0.850; this contradicts the line above that shows 0.71... as output.  I noticed your question title says something about evaluating the function and its derivative, however $\sigma'(0.8979...) \approx$ $0.7107...\cdot(1-0.7107...) \approx$ $0.205592$, so it's not at all clear to me where 0.850 and 0.805 came from.